# Optimizing a distribution to a much more flatter distribution

Tags: optimization, simulation

I have a distribution of values that are the output of a simulation(not stochastic). I want to optimize the parameter such that output distribution are a lot more flatter than they are with non-optimized parameters.
Minimize peak and variance?

Comment: To robust the parameters of a complex system Mont-Carlo simulation is one of the best. Do you look that?

Answer (score 2):

"Flatter" is in the eye of the beholder. Minimizing the range of values would be worth considering.